# Google cloud storage permission only on some object

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, acl, bucket

i have a bucket with multiple folders and each folders contains multiple object (pdf). Is possible to allow only some user to see only specific object(is ok if he can see other folder)?

I tried to apply the reader acl permission only on some object after I created them like this:

`myFile.acl.add({ entity: 'group-' + email, role: 'READER' })`

But the user doesn't see the bucket, so I gave to him the "Storage Object Viewer" permission but now he can see all the objects.

Group is correct (i hope), i created a group with the specific users.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I edited my answer in order to provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the role of `READER` you're allowing the user to list the buckets content as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions)

> Allows a user to list a bucket's contents. Also allows a user to read bucket metadata, excluding ACLs.

In order to allow an specific user you can use the addUser function:

```
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  const storage = new Storage();

  async function addFileReader() {
    await storage
      .bucket(bucketName)
      .file(filename)
      .acl.readers.addUser(userEmail);
  }
```

Or if you want to add a group:

```
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  const storage = new Storage();
  async function addFileReader() {
    await storage
      .bucket(bucketName)
      .file(filename)
      .acl.readers.addGroup(groupEmail);
  }
```

Also you can do it from the UI:

1. Go inside the `Storage` section
2. Click on the specific bucket that you want to grant access to
3. Click on the specific file that you want to grant access
4. Go to `EDIT PERMISSIONS`, in the popup inside `Entity` column select `User` or `Group` in the `Name` column enter the email and select `Reader` in the `Access` column